# Providing Integers.xml for different screen densities

Tags: android, screen

I am using integers.xml  for my app. I provided different integers.xml for different screens such as values-mdpi,values-hdpi,values-xhdpi,values-xxhdpi. However, App always uses mdpi folder for all screen sizes and densities. Why android is not using hdpi folder for hdpi screens but mdpi?

Answer (score 0):

Add this folder

```
 //this for large devices

values-large-hdpi
values-large-mdpi
values-large-xhdpi  

//this for normal devices

values-normal-hdpi
values-normal-mdpi
values-large-xhdpi
```

Hope this help.:)